# Reverse the order of integration of multivariable function: see body

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$$\int_0^1 \int_x^1 6e^{(x/y)} \, dydx$$

Hopefully the formatting came out ok. The (x/y) is supposed to be an exponent

Not sure how to rearrange order of integration of a relatively harder to graph function.

Comment: First: draw a picture ... $x$ between $0$ and $1$ ... $y$ between $x$ and $1$.  What region is that in the $x$-$y$ plane?

Answer (score 0):

In the given integral, x goes from x= 0 to x= 1 and, for each x, y goes from the line y= x up to y= 1.

In an xy-plane that is the right triangle with sides on the lines x= 0, y= x, y= 1.

To reverse the order see that, to cover that same triangle, with x and y in the other order, y must go from 0 to 1 and, for each y, x must go from y= 0  to y= x:
$\int_0^1\int_0^x \frac{1}{y}e^{x}dy dx$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Note the shaded integration region in the graph and reverse the integrating order as follows,

$$\int_0^1 \int_x^1 6e^{(x/y)} dydx=\int_0^1 \int_0^y 6e^{(x/y)} dxdy=6\int_0^1(e-1)y\>dy=3(e-1)$$